# Can transparent text technically be WCAG compliant if an opaque image of the text is in the same location?

Tags: html, pdf, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

## Background

I'm working on a solution for displaying PDFs, that has very specific requirements. Basically we need to manage placement of editable fields on top of these user-uploaded documents, for purposes of electronic signing. We've decided what works best for our engineering needs is to render a canvas layer that displays the PDF image, along with a text layer for the corresponding text content from the document.

The text should be available for use by screen reader and other user interaction, e.g. highlighting. However, we don't want to have to worry about the text layer perfectly matching the image pixel for pixel, just nearly the same placement as the image, so we've made the text layer transparent. I suppose the text is hidden, but it's not. Using the `aria-hidden` attribute would hide the text from screen reader use. Very simplified markup:

```html
<div>
    <!-- The PDF document "image" is rendered here via our JS processes. The image will almost always be some black-and-white form. -->
    <canvas id="image-layer" />

    <!-- The text content of the PDF document is rendered here via our JS processes, placing it nearly directly over the image layer, so as to line up with it as close as possible, but transparent in color. -->
    <div id="text-layer" style="opacity: 0">
        <p>various elements containing text here</p>
    </div>
```

## Question

This isn't technically WCAG compliant because of the incorrect text color contrast ratio to the background. But practically speaking, I believe it is compliant because the text is visible and available for use. I'm curious, what if anything can or should be done to make this text layer markup technically compliant?

Comment: screen readers do not read a document by pixels but their markup! contrast ratios are not a set in stone rule for accessibility. There are also enough studies that proof that a better contrast ratio is not always more readable as an example by the Penn State University. However, hiding text from a user by using opacity or making the font color transparent is never an accessible way. Rather you should use the WAI-ARIA attributes to add information specifically for screen readers.

Comment: As an example you can use `aria-label` to be used as a text that will be read by screen readers in case an element has no child elements that can be read by screen readers such as only child elements with the `aira-hidden` attribute. PS your question should not be if it is WAI-ARIA compliment but WCAG 2.1 compliment!

Comment: Updated to mention WCAG. Thank you. I don't think `aria-label` is necessary as this is just text content. Labels are generally for controls that don't need a description. Content should be self-explanatory, as it would be in this case. This text is already available to the screen reader and I'm just wondering if there's something more I should be doing. But as you said contrast is not as concrete of a rule as others, so what I'm doing may be good enough.

Comment: ARIA isn't made for long text, so the approach of equivalent visually hidden text isn't that bad. However, this is quite a bad workaround for a bad solution. Why do you use a canvas ? Why don't you show text directly ? Canvas shouldn't be used for text content like a PDF. You should make your PDF accessible instead.

Comment: @mikkelrd I designed a signing app as well and would be open to exchange ideas in chat

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems quite elegant because it’s simple, allows for semantic markup in the text and it being read out by screen readers by following the cursor.

And you don’t have to worry about contrast, if your Image of text provides [enough contrast (4.5:1 for WCAG AA)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/contrast-minimum). The transparent text can be seen as the text alternative for the image.

---

But an image of text will fail [Criterion 1.4.5 Images of Text (Level AA)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/images-of-text#dfn-visually-customized), if it’s not adjustable by the user.

> The image of text can be visually customized to the user's requirements;
> visually customized
> the font, size, color, and background can be set

And there are other requirements for adjustment of text contents, that an image will fail:

- [Resize Text (Level AA)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/resize-text)
- [Reflow (Level AA)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/reflow)
- [Text Spacing (Level AA)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/text-spacing)

The transparent text would adapt, but is not visible. Additionally, it would no longer match the layout of the image.

---

To make document signing accessible, the document itself needs to be accessible. Good PDF readers fulfil the above criteria, there might be ready to use libraries out there, like [PDF.js by Mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

I guess there are legal implications as well: **Is the signature valid, if the user cannot have read the document?**

There’s also an interesting discussion about accessibility of user generated content here: [WCAG 2.1 AA Compliance and User-Generated Content - what do you do with content that you don't control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788578/wcag-2-1-aa-compliance-and-user-generated-content-what-do-you-do-with-content)

#### Suggested solution

The app might mark a document as accessible or not, before the user can go about signing it.

If it’s not accessible, the text contents can be directly viewed (without overlaying the image) and signed.

The signature metadata then must clarify that the signing user only had access to the text contents.

Comment: Some great feedback, thank you. We've already considered most of what you've pointed out. We are using PDF.js to help with display, and with extracting the text layer. But as I mentioned, we extracted the two layers for the purpose of having greater control over display and adding an managing an additional layer, which is for positioned form fields. We have implemented the ability to zoom in and out for resizing needs. We'll take a look at the info about User-Generated Content.

Comment: I’m sorry for the bad news, but zooming is not a solution for resizing needs, as it requires scroll in two dimensions. That’s what [Reflow](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/reflow.html) is about.

Comment: But... there's no way to reflow an image. I'm talking about zooming in on the image, just as one does with any PDF viewer. I think what you said about the text layer essentially acting as alt text for an image is the best way for the user to consider the issue. If the user employs at least partial sight, they can see the layout of the form as depicted by the PDF, along with raw text that can be read to them. If they employ less sight, they still have the text content available.

Comment: That’s exactly the issue, hence an image of text will fail WCAG AA.
An accessible PDF does allow for reflow. Acrobat Reader for mobile, f.e. will do that.